# sphinxの`code-block`のハイライトを無効化するには、言語に`text`と`none`どちらを指定するのがよいですか？

Tags: python, sphinx

## 実行環境

- Python 3.9.6
- sphinx 4.4.0

## やりたいこと

`code-block`ディレクティブのハイライトを無効にしたいです。

```
.. code-block:: 

   list set dict ...
```

デフォルトの言語は`python3`に近いものなので、下図のようにハイライトされてしまいます。

https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/configuration.html#confval-highlight_language

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

## 質問

`code-block`の言語に`none`か`text`（`pygments.lexers.special.TextLexer`）を指定すれば、ハイライトが無効化されることが分かりました。
この2つには違いがあるのでしょうか？違いがあるのなら、どちらを指定するのがよいのでしょうか？

```
.. code-block:: text

   list set dict ...
```

```
.. code-block:: none

   list set dict ...
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

明示的に「無効」を表現したいのであれば `none` を指定するのが良さそうです。

`none` はSphinxがPygmentsのTextLexerにマッピングしています。
`text` はSphinxがPygmentsのlexer取得を行い、TextLexerが取得されます。

どちらの場合でもPygmentsのTextLexerが使用されます。

---

PygmentsのLexer一覧は以下で確認できます。
https://pygments.org/docs/lexers/

Sphinxが `none` を受け付けることについては以下のドキュメントで確認できます。
https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/restructuredtext/directives.html#showing-code-examples

Sphinxで`none`を`TextLexer`にマッピングする処理は以下のコードで確認できます。
https://github.com/sphinx-doc/sphinx/blob/f38bd8e9529d50e5cceffe3ca55be4b758529ff7/sphinx/highlighting.py#L36

Comment: `none`だけでなく`python`や`c`も、SphinxがPygmentsのlexerにマッピングしているんですね。参考になりました。